# Index Error: My snake game has an Error that I need help fixing

Tags: python-3.x

There is a problem in my snake game code and I am asking the community of stack overflow to help me out, there is a error in the update function which is in my class and seems to be coming from the screen update and the dir (direction) variable should still be stop but it still runs the code before I have even pressed the button.

I have tried writing the if function in another way but that still doesn't help.

```
import tkinter
import random
import time
class snakegame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.delay = 0.1
        self.foodx = random.randint(0, 10)
        self.foody = random.randint(0, 10)
        self.screen = tkinter.Tk()
        self.screen.config(bg='black')
        self.segments = []
        self.dir = 'stop'
        self.game = []
        self.square_list = []
        self.head = head()
        for row in range(10):
            rowList = []
            square_row = []
            for column in range(10):
                rowList.append(0)
            self.game.append(rowList)
            self.square_list.append(square_row)

        for row, rowList in enumerate(self.game):
            for column, columnEntry in enumerate(self.game):
                square = tkinter.Label(self.screen, text='    ', relief='raised')
                square.grid(row=row, column=column)
                square.config(bg='black')
                self.square_list[row].append(square)
        self.square_list[5][5].config(bg='green')
        self.square_list[self.foody][self.foodx].config(bg='red')
        self.screen.bind('w', self.up())
        self.screen.bind('s', self.down())
        self.screen.bind('a', self.left())
        self.screen.bind('d', self.right())
        while True:
            time.sleep(self.delay)
            self.update()
    def up(self):
        if self.dir != 'down':
            self.dir = 'up'
    def down(self):
        if self.dir != 'up':
            self.dir = 'down'
    def left(self):
        if self.dir != 'right':
            self.dir = 'left'
    def right(self):
        if self.dir != 'left':
            self.dir = 'right'
    def update(self):
        if self.head.x == self.foodx and self.head.y == self.foody:
            self.delay -= 0.001
            self.square_list[self.foody][self.foodx].config(bg='black')
            self.foodx = random.randint(0, 9)
            self.foody = random.randint(0, 9)
            self.square_list[self.foody][self.foodx].config(bg='green')            
            newsegment = segment(segments[-1].x, segments[-1].y)
            self.segments.append(newsegment)
        if self.dir == 'left':
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='black')
            count = 0
            for segment in self.segments:
                count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = self.head.x
                    segment.y = self.head.y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')
                else:
                    place = count - 1
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = segments[place].x
                    segment.y = segments[place].y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')
            self.head.x -= 1
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='green')
        if self.dir == 'right':
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='black')
            count = 0
            for segment in self.segments:
                count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = self.head.x
                    segment.y = self.head.y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')
                else:
                    place = count - 1
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = segments[place].x
                    segment.y = segments[place].y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')

            self.head.x += 1
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='green')
        if self.dir == 'up':
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='black')
            count = 0
            for segment in self.segments:
                count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = self.head.x
                    segment.y = self.head.y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')
                else:
                    place = count - 1
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = segments[place].x
                    segment.y = segments[place].y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')

            self.head.y += 1
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='green')
        if self.dir == 'down':
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='black')
            count = 0
            for segment in self.segments:
                count += 1
                if count == 1:
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = self.head.x
                    segment.y = self.head.y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')
                else:
                    place = count - 1
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='black')
                    segment.x = segments[place].x
                    segment.y = segments[place].y
                    self.square_list[segment.y][segment.x].config(bg='green')

            self.head.y -= 1
            self.square_list[self.head.y][self.head.x].config(bg='green')
        if self.head.x > 9 or self.head.x < 0 or self.head.y > 9 or self.head.y < 0:
            pass
        for segment in self.segments:
            if self.head.x == segment.x and self.head.y == segment.y:
                pass
class head:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = self.y = 5

class segment:
    def __init__(self, posx, posy):
        self.x = posx
        self.y = posy

mysnakegame = snakegame()
```

I should expect the if to not run but I get the following error:

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snakegame.py", line 149, in <module>
    mysnakegame = snakegame()
  File "snakegame.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.square_list[self.foody][self.foodx].config(bg='red')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It is considered good practice to post only the relevant code. This way, it is easier for other people to read and check your code.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full traceback which includes the line number and call-trace of the offending statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is in the following lines:

```py
self.screen.bind('w', self.up())
self.screen.bind('s', self.down())
self.screen.bind('a', self.left())
self.screen.bind('d', self.right())
```

They should be

```py
self.screen.bind('w', self.up)
self.screen.bind('s', self.down)
self.screen.bind('a', self.left)
self.screen.bind('d', self.right)
```

You just want to bind such functions, but you are actually calling them. They are then changing the value of `self.dir` to something else, and that is why you are having such unexpected behavior.